# Android getting UTFDataFormatException reading in UTF from text file

Tags: android, utf, datainputstream

I'm noticing in my event logs for my Android app that I'm getting UTFDataFormatException errors. The file I am reading from is written by my app although as it stores information about user's stories, it could contain any kinds of characters/strings. I'm wondering if there is a problem reading/writing certain characters?

I write by using:

```
dos.writeUTF(myJSONString);
```

and I read in using:

```
textJSONString = dis.readUTF();
```

Some of the error stack traces I have logged are:

```
class: class java.io.UTFDataFormatException

message: bad second or third byte at 1795

    java.io.charset.ModifiedUtf8.decode(ModifiedUtf8.java:53) 
java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:444) 
java.io.DataInputStream.decodeUTF(DataInputStream.java:438) 
java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:433)...
```

I've looked up the source for the decode method but I don't understand what is going on/why it is failing:

```
public static String decode(byte[] in, char[] out, int offset, int utfSize) throws UTFDataFormatException {
        int count = 0, s = 0, a;
        while (count < utfSize) {
            if ((out[s] = (char) in[offset + count++]) < '\u0080') {
                s++;
            } else if (((a = out[s]) & 0xe0) == 0xc0) {
                if (count >= utfSize) {
                    throw new UTFDataFormatException("bad second byte at " + count);
                }
                int b = in[offset + count++];
                if ((b & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
                    throw new UTFDataFormatException("bad second byte at " + (count - 1));
                }
                out[s++] = (char) (((a & 0x1F) << 6) | (b & 0x3F));
            } else if ((a & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
                if (count + 1 >= utfSize) {
                    throw new UTFDataFormatException("bad third byte at " + (count + 1));
                }
                int b = in[offset + count++];
                int c = in[offset + count++];
                if (((b & 0xC0) != 0x80) || ((c & 0xC0) != 0x80)) {
                    throw new UTFDataFormatException("bad second or third byte at " + (count - 2));
                }
                out[s++] = (char) (((a & 0x0F) << 12) | ((b & 0x3F) << 6) | (c & 0x3F));
            } else {
                throw new UTFDataFormatException("bad byte at " + (count - 1));
            }
        }
        return new String(out, 0, s);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work with simple files? Do you see anything odd when you open the file with a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the file is corrupted (ie: it isn't properly encoded UTF8). Are you properly closing your file after you write it? I can imagine that you will get these errors if you are writing to a buffered output stream and you don't properly close the stream. Then some of the bytes will not be written and you'll have a corrupted file that cannot be re-read.